# NavigationBar width randomly doubling in page view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode6

The width of the navigation bar is randomly doubling.. You can see this in the print statements. One prints (self.navigationController.navigationBar) in Page1ViewController.viewDidLoad() -- where you see that the navigation bar is the expected width.  However, the second and third prints (viewWillAppear and viewDidApepar, respectively) you can see that the width is twice the original width.

I have no idea why this is happening... Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here is the git project: https://github.com/bhowell2/iOSNavBarDoublingBug

Project Structure:

TabBarController, which has a contentView and a tabBarView. They are set using AutoLayout constraints (which are called after they are added as subviews of the root view).

The TabBarController loads the NavigationController, which is given a root view controller of PageViewController (which has 2 TableViewControllers and 1 UIViewController).

I have also verified this fails with just "regular" UIViewControllers as pages of the PageViewController.

Also, you will see some more strange behavior when running this in iOS 7.1 - Half of the windows is cut off.. (Change TabBarViewController.contentView.clipsToBounds = false/true) to alter this behavior somewhat where the navigation bar "seems to work", but the rest of the views are cut off..

*Using XCode 6.2*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not set up necessary constraints, I just removed all constraints and tried with springs and whatever:

```
for view in [ tabBarView, contentView, navController.view, pageViewController.view ] {
    view.frame = self.view.bounds
    view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
    view.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleHeight
}
```

all looks good.

Comment: thank you. I did this with auto layout constraints. Same effect. However, I'm still perplexed as to WHY this is happening..?

Comment: Because you did not set constraints for all views? You can achieve the same with autolayout, just pin all views that you have to superview edges.

Comment: Also, when you create views in code, make sure you set `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` for each view that will participate in auto layout. However, views created in Interface builder have this set to `FALSE` automatically.